# Fetch requests with React Native

Tags: react-native, fetch

whenever I do fetch requests with react native to an API, it gives me this error code:

[TypeError: Network request failed]

Does anyone know what this means?

I checked Stackoverflow and it was said that I need to update my info.plist, however that didn't fix the issue unfortunately

I added this to my info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>weatherapi.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

This is the code I use to fetch, the URL works. My ReactJS app successfully sends the requests

```
const [degreesCelsius, setDegreesCelsius] = useState(0);

  const fetchInformation = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const result = await fetch(
        "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=140ce0a625221404&q=Berlin&aqi=yes",
      );

      if (result.ok) {
        const data = await result.json();
        setDegreesCelsius(data.current.temp_c);
        console.log(degreesCelsius);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, could you please post an example of the code you have tried along with the url?

Comment: hey @Asleepace,thank you. added the code

Comment: Hello, we need your fetch code to see what the problem might be. Could you update the post with it?

Comment: hey @SlothOverlord, yes I added the fetch request too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this isn't an issue with the `fetch` request the domain specified in your .plist appears to also be incorrect. For now I would just recommend setting `NSAllowArtbitraryLoads` key to `true` which will allow your app to make any request as long as it's using [https](https://www.ssl.com/faqs/what-is-https/)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>myweather.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

During development I find this approach much easier, if security is paramount to the application then you can come back and update the allowed domains later.

```js
const result = await fetch(
  'https://api.myweather.com/' // this also needs to be a url,
);
```

Also the url in your fetch request needs to be valid, since it appears you are using a subdomain as well you will need to add the `NSIncludesSubdomains` key as well.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsexceptionallowsinsecurehttploads?language=objc

Also make sure to recompile after updating the .plist either from within xcode or by running `npx react-native run-ios` :)

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, would you change localhost to the api link?

it doesn't work this way unfortunately

Comment: I would keep that there since that's how remote debugging works in react-native, but is the api you are using `http` or `https`?

Comment: yes you will also need another entry to allow insecure `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` please make sure the entry in the .plist also matches the domain in the `fetch` I'll update the post with an example

Comment: so the url in my fetch is valid, I just didn't want to include the whole api link. 

I used the HTTPLoads as well, but it still doesn't work. When you say the entry, do you mean where it currently says localhost?

Comment: @ashketchup I think the issue is you are adding a subdomain, instead you should at the domain such as `myweather.com` along with the `NSIncludesSubdomains` key as well. Just updated the post

Comment: it still gives the same error unfortunately

Comment: @ashketchup could you post the `url` you are using, it's hard to determine what the issue might be without that

Comment: I updated my post, thats how my info.plist is looking like right now

Comment: @ashketchup yeah so remove the `api` in the .plist so it looks like this: `weatherapi.com` and also make sure to have the correct url in your `fetch`

Comment: I tried that too, still doesn't work :/

Comment: @ashketchup could you please update the `fetch` code as well (it still has a placeholder value)?

Comment: its a personal API link, I added it but changed the key a bit. The full url works on my ReactJS and web though

Comment: @ashketchup oh sorry please update the actual code where you are making the request and leave the .plist as it was, I think you didn't add the right url to your actual code.

Comment: oh no my bad, I did put it in the fetch in my actual code. I just put it in the .plist on stackoverflow, got confused with the code blocks

Comment: @ashketchup no worries, you are rebuilding the app from xcode as well? In order for the .plist to take effect it needs to be recompiled?

Comment: I'm pressing R on my metro terminal, is that enough?

Comment: @ashketchup ah no when making changes to the plist you will need to rebuild the app either from inside xcode or by running `npx react-native run-ios` again

Comment: @ashketchup haha yeah np!